# non-nullable local variable 'key' must be assigned before it can be used

Tags: flutter

I am trying to assign values after a specific condition has been matched, but I get error saying the variable must be assigned before I can use it.

```
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    doc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;

                // user Id
                var userId = currentUser.uid;

                // Recipient Id
                var recipientId = data['latestMessage']['id'];

                // Defined variables
                String key;
                String name;

                generateChatId() {
                  if (userId.length > recipientId.length) {
                    return userId + '-' + recipientId;
                  } else {
                    return recipientId + '-' + userId;
                  }
                }

                if (doc.id == generateChatId()) {
                  key = data['latestMessage']['id'] as String;
                  name = data['latestMessage']['name'] as String;
                } else if (recipientId == userId) {
                  key = data['latestMessage']['id'] as String;
                  name = data['latestMessage']['name'] as String;
                }

                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(key),
                  subtitle: Text(name),
                )
              }).toList(),
            );
```

In the above code, variables `key` and `name` are defined, then assigned values in the `if` statements. Are the variable then not assigned outside the `if` statements, when used in the `ListTile`?

Answer (score 2):

#### Null safety

> **The reason your code is getting an error is because of Dart's null safety feature. Null safety features added after Flutter 2.0.**

'Key' or 'name' are defined and branches 'if' and 'else-if' are performed. However, if there is no value suitable for the condition of 'if' or 'else-if', no value is assigned to 'key' or 'name'.

**This is why your code is caught by Dart's null safety error.**

There are 3 ways to resolve errors in your code.

##### 1. Use Nullable Type

```dart
    String? key;
    String? name;
```

##### 2. Initialize key variable

```dart
    String key = "";  // "" is not Null
    String name = "";
```

##### 3. Add else conditional statement

```dart
                ...

                if (doc.id == generateChatId()) {
                  key = data['latestMessage']['id'] as String;
                  name = data['latestMessage']['name'] as String;
                } else if (recipientId == userId) {
                  key = data['latestMessage']['id'] as String;
                  name = data['latestMessage']['name'] as String;
                } else {
                  // add your code here
                }

                ...
```

*good luck*

Answer (score 1):

```
return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data? =
                    doc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;

                // user Id
                late var userId = currentUser.uid;

                // Recipient Id
                late var recipientId = data['latestMessage']['id'];

                // Defined variables
                String? key;
                String? name;

                generateChatId() {
                  if (userId.length > recipientId.length) {
                    return userId + '-' + recipientId;
                  } else {
                    return recipientId + '-' + userId;
                  }
                }

                if (doc.id == generateChatId()) {
                  key = data['latestMessage']['id'] as String;
                  name = data['latestMessage']['name'] as String;
                } else if (recipientId == userId) {
                  key = data['latestMessage']['id'] as String;
                  name = data['latestMessage']['name'] as String;
                }

                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(key),
                  subtitle: Text(name),
                )
              }).toList(),
            );
```

try this one